# android - camera app - list of permissions

Tags: android, camera

I want to know what permissions are assigned to the stock camera app in Android 4.4. I tried to look for its AndroidManifest file online, but can't find it. Can anyone point me to some web-link which might help ?

Comment: have you tried looking in Settings >> Apps >> Camera?

Comment: @panini did you down vote me ? :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings > Apps > Camera. It lists all the permissions there.

And it looks like it uses almost all the permissions available ;)

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) you will need the following **basic** permissions & features for the camera itself:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

By looking up in the Settings > Applications > Camera  in the emulator, I found the following settings:

[image]

Most of them are self-explanatory but I would like to explain the folling:

#### [Hardware Controls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html#HARDWARE_CONTROLS):

It is a `PermissonGroup` which is required for recording audio/video etc.

> Used for permissions that provide direct access to the hardware on the
>   device. This includes audio, the camera, vibrator, etc.
>
> Constant Value: `"android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"`

#### [Storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html#STORAGE):

this is required because camara apps also can display captured images which may be stored on the SD card. also required to store images.

> Group of permissions that are related to SD card access.
>
> Constant Value: "android.permission-group.STORAGE"

this is the best resource according to me:

[Camera developer guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest) Please let me know if you require any other explanation regarding a permission.

Comment: No .. I meant .. what permissions the camera app itself uses